# Configuring the local maven cache

Tags: maven, grails

I have an existing local maven cache at d:\repository... that I want grails to use as its maven cache. How do I do this? Currently grails is creating its maven cache under [user home].m2\repository, which I guess is the default place.

How do I configure grails to match the settings of my other (non grails) maven projects?

Comment: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#configurationsAndDependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grails have its own settings file for the repository configuration.

The [configuration sections](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dependencyResolution) of Grails reports it very nicely. Search for the header **Where are the JARs?**

But basically, edit your `.grails/settings.groovy` and set

```
grails.dependency.cache.dir = "d:\repository..."
```

Comment: Minor correction: grails.dependency.cache.dir = "d:/repository..." works  fine. Thank you.